# Visibility.Collapsed is not giving back its space

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

Weird subject so let me explain: I have a Silverlight MainPage with a border control at the top of the page of height 400. Once the user is Authenticated, I navigate to a child page. I also collapse the border on the MainPage. The child page shows correctly but there is a blank 400 space above it where the MainPage border control was before it was collapsed. I thought Visibilty.Collapsed is supposed to surrender back the space it occupies but it doesnt seem to do this. I have set VerticalAlignment='Top' on the frame object in the MainPage and also tried that setting on the child page but neither work.

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Code Updated:

```
 <ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          DataContext='{StaticResource ViewModel}'>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height='400'></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height='*'></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Show the Xaml.  There may be something there you're overlooking.

Comment: Ok - on the MainPage (partial xaml because of character restrictions when answering)  <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" VerticalAlignment='Top'
                    Grid.Row='1'>
                <navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"
                                  Source="/Home"
                                  Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated"
                                  NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed">
                    <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
                        <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                            <uriMapper ...

Comment: You need to show the Xaml surrounding the "border control at the top of the page" as it is likely the grid containing it has a fixed size row. Can you edit the original question?

Comment: @greg - please **edit** the code into the question.

Comment: HiTech - you got it :  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height='400'></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height='*'></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

Comment: Thanks Chris - will edit in question in future -

Comment: Myles - you were right too. Will mark as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to resolve this by wrapping the border in a grid and then setting the height of the RowDefinition containing the border to Auto.  The following test example worked for me:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Height="760" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Azure">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="HeaderRow"  Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="TabRow" Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="0" Background="Bisque" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Name="HeaderBorder"
                        CornerRadius="10">
        <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">Test2</TextBlock>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Hide Border" Click="Button_Click"></Button>

</Grid>
```

And in the code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HeaderBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```